# How to get tweet ID in Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, status

I want to search a keyword and get 70 tweets, and then list all tweet's IDs. I don't know how, please help.

```
import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
auth.set_access_token('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
user = api.me()



import time

time_limit_sec = 600
start_time = time.time()



for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="books", result_type="recent").items(70):  
    status = api.get_status(id) 
    id = status.id 
    print("The ID of the status is :"  + str(id)) 
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

The tweet id is under _json['id']. Don't use *break*, it will limit to 70 as you set items(70).

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="books", result_type="recent").items(70):  
    print("The tweet id is:", tweet._json['id'])
```